# sql boolean truth test: zero OR null

Tags: mysql

Is there way to test for both 0 and NULL with one equality operator?

I realize I could do this:

`WHERE field = 0 OR field IS NULL`

But my life would be a hundred times easier if this would work:

`WHERE field IN (0, NULL)`

(btw, why doesn't that work?)

I've also read about converting NULL to 0 in the SELECT statement (with COALESCE). The framework I'm using would also make this unpleasant.

Realize this is oddly specific, but is there any way to test for 0 and NULL with one WHERE predicate?

Comment: Answering the "why doesn't that work" part: `WHERE field IN (0, NULL)` is `WHERE field = 0 or field = NULL` the last case is `unknown`

Comment: If you expand your IN clause, it should be clearer as to why it doesn't work: `field IN (0, NULL)` is equivalent to `field = 0 OR field = NULL` and you cannot use the "=" operator to test for NULL, the result is unknown.

Comment: note that if you want the inverse of that, field <> 0 works. But it cannot be negated as any operation on a null result is still null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work because `field In(0,Null)` is the equivalent of `field = 0 Or field = Null` as opposed to `field = 0 Or field Is Null`. One option is to use a Case expression:

```
Case 
When field = 0 Then 1 
When field Is Null Then 1
End = 1
```

The better option is to stick with your original `field = 0 OR field Is Null` as it makes your intent clearer.

Answer (score 13):

I would write that comparison using the handy [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
IFNULL(field, 0) = 0
```

And in response to your question about the IN function:

> "To comply with the SQL standard, IN
>   returns NULL not only if the
>   expression on the left hand side is
>   NULL, but also if no match is found in
>   the list and one of the expressions in
>   the list is NULL." -[the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` statement is better IMO, However you can try `WHERE !IFNULL(field, 0)`?